# Setting up UserRole management with MVC6 and the new Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-identity-3

I have a new asp.net (core 1.0) mvc6 web application with the latest version of identity 3.x.

I am trying to figure out what I have to do on my own and what is already plug and play for me with Identity 3.x.

**Here is my goal:**

**I want to create the following:**
UserManagement page (will list the users from AspNetUsers table and can add new users here)

UserDetail page (can add roles to a user here which will get saved in the AspNetUserRoles table)

RoleManagement page (will list the roles from AspNetRoles table and can add new roles to the system here)

**I am trying to figure out:**
If how much of the above the built in UserManager class can help me out with. I noticed there are RemoveFromRoleAsync, RemoveFromRolesAsync, AddToRoleAsync, and AddToRolesAsync functions. I can most likely call these functions to do the saving, but I am assuming I will have to create my own functions to list the Users and Roles in grids.

Comment: Just so everyone knows it ended up being really easy for me to use these managers to create full User, Role, and UserRole management in my application. There is a function for every single thing I needed. I just had to create the Action Methods in my Controller for all of the CRUD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the UserManager and the RoleManager.
UserManager has Users and RoleManager has Roles properties.

```
//assuming you have injected these into your controller's constructor
var users = _userManager.Users.ToList();
var roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
```

If you want to learn more of what you can do with Identity, we did a free course on identity https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/customizing-asp-net-authentication-with-identity-8647

Comment: I ended up creating two controllers: Roles Controller and Users Controller using the built-in async scaffolding. Then like you said I injected the managers as necessary and made all ActionMethods work! One weird thing is that it isn't possible to make the Index Action method which simply returns _userManager.Users.ToList(); Async... Do you know of a way? I can't put await before it since .Users isn't an async method.

Comment: Disregard my previous question, I ended up importing Microsoft.Data.Entity and just calling .ToListAsync(); at the end of _roleManager.Roles.Select